# JBOSS 4.2.3 default encoding while base64 decoding

Tags: jboss-4.2.x

I am using `JBOSS 4.2.3` and `UsernamePasswordLoginModule` class being extended by custom class which overrides method `validatePassword`. This method has two parameters `inputPassword` and `expectedPassword`. Client sends `Base64 encoded loginId:password` to the server and server decodes using `base64`. Server decodes credentials using `iso-8859-1` (I verified after looking accented characters on online conversion tool and that was equivalent to iso output not UTF-8). Since iso does not supports international characters and I need to use UTF-8 but I did not figure it out where this iso encoding has done if we are doing `Base64 decode`. I searched `Base64` decode method but charset was not specified.

My query is that do we have any mechanism to set encoding in above said scenario. Requirement is that client will send `UTF-8 data` and I need to decode using `UTF8`. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Base64 encoding and decoding of strings is a two step process:

[Encoding] **String -> byte[]** -> String (base64 encoded)
[Decoding] String (base64 encoded) -> **byte[] -> String**

The character encoding needs to be set in the steps highlighted in **bold**.

For encoding that would mean doing:

```
String s;
byte[] bytes = s.getBytes("UTF-8");
```

For decoding it would be:

```
byte[] bytes;
String s = new String(bytes, "UTF-8");
```